# NUnit user credential dialog is not shown

Tags: c#, nunit, prompt

I need to write some Unit tests for a server based application with NUnit in C#. These tests require a connection to a server and the server asks with a dialog prompt for user credentials.

The problem is: when I try to run these tests, NUnit calls with [OneTimeSetUp] the function to connect to the server and then waits for the user input for the credentials. But the dialog prompt won't show and I don't have access to the server connection class

Comment: I think you're in a very bad place if you need to write unit tests that require a user interface and being able to talk to a server. Additionally you have *very little* information about this user interface in your question, such as even the type of application. Is it winforms? wpf? web? webservice? Basically, nobody here can *answer* your question, the most anyone here can do is start discussing the problem with you and open-ended discussions are not really good *question*-material here on Stack Overflow. I suggest you find a chatroom somewhere and discuss it with people.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will consider finding a suitable chatroom